# Pydev crashes Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

I have set Pydev up for Eclipse Mars.1 on Windows 10 64-Bit system. The version is Pydev 4.5.1, when I open Eclipse it asks me to set PyDev preferences for Eclipse this however crashes my Eclipse and can only be exited using a forced close. Does anyone know why this is?

[image: Image shows the crash]

Comment: Humm, something odd going there as this works for me in the same platform... Please report that as an issue into the pydev tracker: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ and add the info from the halt by showing the stack (see: https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock for details on how to get it).

Comment: Okay thanks. I will do that. I had to delete and reinstall both eclipse and pydev. It has worked for now but I'm not sure if I have permanently fixed it